# Cronjob priorities - execution time and exit

Tags: cron, execution

I have the following into a crontab and have 7 of these...at range of 15 minutes between one and the other:

```
50 8 * * * wget -q -O - http://domain.com/path/to/script.php?xxx=3
```

this script calls mysql, selects every record from a table, does something and updates a certain value...
while usually this script requires about +5minutes to end...and 2 or 3 disappear from running processes...other 3 or 4 do not...it seems they overlap

```
7020    root    0.0 %   wget -q -O - http://domain.com/path/to/script.php?xxx=3
```

now, can be a priority problem? how to set a priority into crontab (with nice?) ? how priority manages the execution time? with highest priority the process exits before?

if i do `mysql > SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G`
they seem are yet running after 3 hours !
and also...during these sql processes the tables are readable and if not, how to avoid? the pages are served more slowly as usual

Comment: WHY OFF TOPIC? ARE you SERIOUS?

Comment: I can ask a question or not? What the benefit of a question if i cannot ask?

Comment: did you get your answer in the end?